# Wayland logout CPU 100%

Tags: kubuntu, reboot, wayland

After I switch to logout I have 100% load to CPU it never stops until reboot. I've found that this is Akonadi, but after kill such processed, others also show signs of heavy CPU usage. I'm using Kubuntu 21.04.[image]